# addressable/uri gives params in alphabetical order in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, addressable-gem

addressable/uri gives params in **alphabetic order**. If I want to get the query params as in the hash(i.e nonce, method, rate, order_type, quantity) how should I change my code?

```
2.1.0 :060 > require "addressable/uri"
2.1.0 :061 > uri = Addressable::URI.new
2.1.0 :062 > uri.query_values = Hash["nonce" => 1405069051840, "method" => "a", "rate" => "rate", "order_type" => "order_type", "quantity" => "quantity"]
 => {"nonce"=>1405069051840, "method"=>"a", "rate"=>"rate", "order_type"=>"order_type", "quantity"=>"quantity"} 
2.1.0 :063 > params = uri.query
 => "method=a&nonce=1405069051840&order_type=order_type&quantity=quantity&rate=rate"
```

I need output like this:(as I passed)

```
"nonce=1405069051840&method=a&rate=rate&order_type=order_type&quantity=quantity"
```

Output now is (alphabetical order)

```
"method=a&nonce=1405069051840&order_type=order_type&quantity=quantity&rate=rate"
```

Comment: why does it need to be in alphabetical order?

Comment: Hashes are not ordered. Any order you see is implementation-dependent and a coincidence.

Comment: @dax - I am saying this should not be in alphabetic order but it is in alphabetic order

Comment: @simonwo- Then why it comes in alphabetic order?

Comment: okay...why should it NOT be in alphabetical order?  it's a hash.  you call it with keys which are not order dependent

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pass in an `Array` of [`[key, value]` pairs](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable/blob/master/lib/addressable/uri.rb#L1582) instead of a `Hash` if you want the [Addressable gem](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) to [preserve the order of the paramaters](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable/blob/a15b7045a09911bcc47b106200554809c879a5f6/lib/addressable/uri.rb#L1616-L1618).

```
uri.query_values = [ [ "nonce", 1405069051840 ], ["method", "a" ], ... ]
```